# Access env variable dynamically with parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables, javascript-objects

I'm trying to write a small Vue plugin that just returns the env variable content. Similar to PHPs `env()` method.
Context: I need a url in multiple components, obviously I put this in the `.env` file because it could possibly change in the future. You cannot use `process.env` inside of the components template though because: `Property or method "process" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

This is what I've tried to far:
I call the prototype function in a mounted hook like this:
`console.log('test: ' + this.env('MIX_COB_PARTNER_URL'));`

```js
import _get from "lodash/get";

const Env = {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.env = function (name) {
            console.log(name); // "MIX_VARIABLE"
            console.log(typeof name); // string

            // variant 1
            return process.env[name]; // undefined

            // variant 2
            return process.env["MIX_VARIABLE"]; // "works" but isnt dynamic obviously

            // variant 3-5 with lodash
            return _get(process.env, name); // undefined
            // or
            return _get(process, 'env[' + name + ']'); // undefined
            // or
            return _get(process.env, '[' + name + ']'); // undefined, worth a try lol
            
            // variant 6
            const test = "MIX_VARIABLE"
            return process.env[test]; // again just for the sake of trying
        }
    }
}

export default Env;
```

I know that usually `object[variable]` works fine. But somehow it doesnt in this case, maybe it has to do with the fact that the `process.env` is empty when accessed without a key and the `[name]` ist as "direct" as `.MIX_VARIABLE` would be.

Does this just not work?
Ive researched and found some people (e.g. here on SO) suggesting this type of accessing (`process.env[variable]`) so I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe starting to enhance your JS would be the best thing you could do. 
If you are using build tool like vitejs this should not be a problem to access through process.env or vite suggested import.meta. If you solely run this in browser you can set a global constant for that. Since if you may know there is JS for browser(client) and server(backend), you've stated none. Since **process** is a global var provided by nodejs and it is never predefined in browser.

Comment: @mentorgashi The problem isnt about process.env in general. It works fine generally. Its about dynamically retrieving env variables. I use Laravel Mix and VueJS, I cant just switch build tools because sth small like this. Why does object[variable] work but process.env[variable] doesnt?

Comment: idk as quick try you may try, const someVar = Object.assign({}, process.env); then someVar[variable]

Comment: Doesnt work unfortunately...

Comment: @beeftony Did you get this to work? I'm trying to do the same. Looks like Vue does a search/replace in the code text for env variable names, which is why what you've written doesn't work. (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code) I suspect the answer is "just doesn't work", but I'm hoping for an alternative.

Comment: Hmm. I was confused by webpack module naming: this is actually working for me. I have a utility function `getEnv(name) => { return process.env[name] }` which seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your environment variable name needs to start with `VUE_APP_` in order to be picked up by Vue's environment variable processing. So, maybe rename `MIX_VARIABLE` to `VUE_APP_MIX_VARIABLE`? (See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)